# Possible bug in Scala 2.10.3 compiler

Tags: scala

I ran into some code that looks pretty much like this:

```
object SomeOddThing extends App {
  val c: C = new C
  val a: A = c
  val b: B = c
  // these will all print None
  println(a.x)
  println(b.x)
  println(c.x)
}

abstract class A {
  def x: Option[String] = None
}

abstract class B extends A {
  override def x: Option[String] = Some("xyz")
}

class C extends B {
  // x now has type None.type instead of Option[String]
  override def x = None
}

trait T {
  this: B =>
  override def x = Some("ttt")
}

// this won't compile with the following error
// error: overriding method x in class C of type => None.type;
//  method x in trait T of type => Some[String] has incompatible type
// class D extends C with T {}
//       ^
class D extends C with T {}
```

This looks like a bug to me. Either the type of `C.x` should be inferred correctly or the class shouldn't compile at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec 4.6.4 only promises to infer a conforming type for the result type of the overriding method.

See https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7212 and be thankful you didn't throw.

Maybe it will change:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/6vemF4hOA9A

Update:

Covariant result types are natural.  It's not grotesque that it infers what it would normally do. And that you can't widen the type again.  It's maybe suboptimal, as that other issue puts it. (Speaking to my comment that it's an improvement rather than a bug per se.)

My comment on the ML:

> This falls under "always annotate interface methods, including
>   interface for extension by subclass."

There are lots of cases where using an inferred type for an API method commits you to a type you had rather avoided. This is also true for the interface you present to subclasses.

For this problem, we're asking the compiler to retain the last explicitly ascribed type, which is reasonable, unless it isn't.  Maybe we mean don't infer singleton types, or Nothing, or something like that. /thinking-aloud

```
scala> trait A ; trait B extends A ; trait C extends B
defined trait A
defined trait B
defined trait C

scala> trait X { def f: A }
defined trait X

scala> trait Y extends X { def f: B }
defined trait Y

scala> trait Z extends Y { def f: C }
defined trait Z

scala> trait X { def f: A = new A {} }
defined trait X

scala> trait Y extends X { override def f: B = new B {} }
defined trait Y

scala> trait Z extends Y { override def f: C = new C {} }
defined trait Z

scala> trait ZZ extends Z { override def f: A = new C {} }
<console>:13: error: overriding method f in trait Z of type => C;
 method f has incompatible type
       trait ZZ extends Z { override def f: A = new C {} }
                                         ^
```

To the question, what does it mean for None.type to conform to Option?

```
scala> implicitly[None.type <:< Option[_]]
res0: <:<[None.type,Option[_]] = <function1>
```

to show that None.type, the singleton type of the None object, is in fact an Option.

Usually, one says that the compiler avoids inferring singleton types, even when you kind of want it to.

[Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/modular-programming-using-objects.html#27.7) says, "Usually such types are too specific to be useful."

Comment: there is now an [issue regarding this](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8159)